# Error Reading Image

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

When I tried to open a simple smile.png image using

```java
package com.java3d.java3d.graphics;

 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
 import java.io.File;

 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

 public class Texture {
public static Render floor = loadBitMap("smile.png");
 public Texture(){}
public static Render loadBitMap(String fileName) {
    try {
        BufferedImage image =          ImageIO.read(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(fileName));
        System.out.print(image==null);
        int width = image.getWidth();
        System.out.println(width);
        int height = image.getHeight();
        System.out.println(height);
        
        
        System.out.println(image.getRGB(4, 4)); 
        Render result = new Render(width, height);

        image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, result.pixels, 0, width);
        
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("CRASH!");
 throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
 }
```

it returns every pixel as -1; what could be causing this problem?
Here is the image:
[image: The Image I use]

Comment: *"I tried to open a simple smile.png"*  Load that image into the question.

Comment: `} catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("CRASH!");
 throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }`  Change that to `} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
    }`

Comment: I can't, it must be like that or else there is no reason to run the game.

Comment: *"it must be like that"*  Like what?  Broken?  I have read that comment several times and still have no idea what it is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class QuickTest {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLRBU.png"));
        System.out.println(image==null);
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        System.out.println(width + "x" + height);
        for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
                System.out.print(image.getRGB(i, j) + "," ); 
            }
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    }
}
```

### OP

```
false
8x8
-16711936,-16711936,-16711936,-16711936,-16711936,-16711936,-16711936,-16711936,
-16711936,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-16711936,
-16711936,-1,-65536,-1,-65536,-1,-1,-16711936,
-16711936,-1,-1,-1,-1,-65536,-1,-16711936,
-16711936,-1,-1,-1,-1,-65536,-1,-16711936,
-16711936,-1,-65536,-1,-65536,-1,-1,-16711936,
-16711936,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-16711936,
-16711936,-16711936,-16711936,-16711936,-16711936,-16711936,-16711936,-16711936,
```

Comment: +1 but I think you may need to swap the parameters to `getRGB()`.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't resist this variation of @Andrew's example. Given the byte order `ARGB`, one can almost see the green border and red features. Note that the *x* and *y* parameters to `getRGB()` represent *column* and *row*, respectively.

```
false
8x8
FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FF00FF00 
FF00FF00 FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FF00FF00 
FF00FF00 FFFFFFFF FFFF0000 FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFF0000 FFFFFFFF FF00FF00 
FF00FF00 FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FF00FF00 
FF00FF00 FFFFFFFF FFFF0000 FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFF0000 FFFFFFFF FF00FF00 
FF00FF00 FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFF0000 FFFF0000 FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FF00FF00 
FF00FF00 FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FF00FF00 
FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FF00FF00 FF00FF00
```

Code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class QuickTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLRBU.png"));
        System.out.println(image == null);
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        System.out.println(width + "x" + height);
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
                System.out.printf("%04X ", image.getRGB(col, row));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```